# Salesforce AssertEquals not working as expected

Tags: salesforce, apex, assertion

[image]

Why is this error thrown? I'm expecting it to pass.

Note : Without this assertion the code works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

I would try explicitly requesting the Last Name field in the SELECT clause as seen below:

```
for(Contact contact : [SELECT Id LastName, Name FROM Contact]){
    System.assertEquals(lastName, contact.LastName);
}
```

FYI, it would have been easier to answer this question if the code was in text and not an image.